# Why can't I use new string in the debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

The following code compiles successfully:

```
string foo = new string(new char[] { 'b', 'a', 'r' });
```

The following code fails to be evaluated if pasted into the watch window or the Immediate Window:

```
new string(new char[] { 'b', 'a', 'r' });
```

The error message is:

```
'new string(new char[] { 'b', 'a', 'r' })' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
    base {System.SystemException}: {"Only NewString function evaluation can create a new string."}
    Message: "Only NewString function evaluation can create a new string."
    ParamName: null
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: See [this blog post](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2009/03/string-construtor-stringchar-value.html).

Comment: This is now "fixed" in VS 2015, I'm guessing because it uses Roslyn.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The C# expression evaluator uses `ICorDebugEval` & `ICorDebugEval2` interfaces to interact with the CLR during a debugging session.  That interface does not allow the calling of any constructor on the `string` type.  Instead it forces all calls to create a new instance of `string` to go through the `ICorDebugEval::NewString` method.  The C# EE does not special case `string` in the EE hence it tries to call the constructor directly and fails.

Note you won't see this exception with VB.Net in Visual Studio 2010.  It will special case calls to the `string` constructors by evaluating the arguments and forwarding the resulting `string` object onto `ICorDebugEval::NewString`

Comment: Why is there a `NewString` method at all? Why wouldn't strings be created via `NewObject`?

Comment: @Brian, I don't know the history as to why they made that distinction and when i asked awhile back the current code maintainers didn't either.

Comment: Just to note, as a workaround, you can use this: 
new System.Text.StringBuilder().Append(new char[] {'b', 'a', 'r'})).ToString()

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with the immutability / interning support.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i never got a good answer about why this limitation existed when I asked about it.  My suspicion though was that it's because it was an internally implemented method.

Comment: @JaredPar Shame, sounds like a potential SO question to me :-) thanks for getting back on this - sorry for the necro-post lol